# Utf-16BE to ISO-8859-1 in PHP

Tags: php, encoding, utf-16

i need to convert a Utf-16BE in ISO-8859-1 in PHP (i'm not an expert in encoding so i don't know if Utf-16 and Utf-16BE are the same thing). I've read somewhere to use the mb_convert_encoding function but i haven't that function because i don't have the multibyte extension installed. So do you know an alternative method to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's also the [iconv module](http://docs.php.net/book.iconv) exposing the [string iconv  (  string $in_charset  ,  string $out_charset  ,  string $str  )](http://docs.php.net/function.iconv) function.
You really don't want to code the conversion yourself, use one of those two modules.